# Bootstrap3 dropdown toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to develop Intranet web application for mobile screen size only, I don't need responsive design technique.

I would like to have a toggle button on the right corner, when pressed it should drop a dropdown menu.

This is my coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Boostrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .navbar-header {
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-right:5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dropdown1">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Schedule <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu unstyled pull-left dropdown-features">
              <li><a href="#">Day One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Day Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Day Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="/dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tested this code using Chrome and Firefox (Ubuntu), it's not working, but when I host this coding [here](http://bootply.com/81910) it's working. How can I find out what is going wrong?

[image: This is the asset directory's permission]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed jquery from 1.10.2 to 1.9.1, then I got things working.